# Average of logs or log of average

Tags: mean, logarithm, clinical-trials

The primary outcome of a clinical trial is the proportion of individuals with a >2 log10 decrease in viral load at Week 24. Viral load is measured on 3 consecutive days at baseline & again at 3 consecutive days at Week 24 (an average is used as variability is expected).

In order to calculate the log decrease, is it correct to either a) log10 the individual results & calculate the average, or b) average the raw results & log10 this?

Eg, Suppose for one individual, results were 1300, 1250, & 2000 are obtained at baseline & at Week 24, results were 700, 600, 450.

Would the log10 decrease be:

a) average(log10(1300),log10(1250),log10(2000)) - average(log10(700),log10(600),log10(450)
= 3.171 - 2.759
= 0.412

b) log10{average(1300,1250,2000)} - log10{average(700,600,450)} =
= log10(1516.67) - log10(583.33)
= 3.181 - 2.766
= 0.415

Comment: You are effectively saying you want the the week 24 viral load to be $30\%$ of less of the baseline viral load.  You then ask whether to use (a) the geometric averages or (b) the arithmetic averages for each week in this calculation.  I am not sure the two points are related: the answer to your question depends on the distribution of measurements in the same week

Answer (score 1):

According to this reference (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_reduction) on log reduction , we have a greater than 2log10 reduction in viral load if

$R = log_{10}c_{b} − log_{10}c_{a}>2$, where $c_{b}$ is the true baseline viral load and the $c_{a}$ is the true viral load at the end of 24 weeks. Both $c_{b}$ and $c_{a}$ are unknown (or unobserved), and needs to be estimated (or measured) first. An average of 3 consecutive measures is used because we want more reliable estimation of $c_{b}$ and $c_{a}$, thus I think based on this interpretation, the second way looks more correct.